# Testing Facade multiple functions

Tags: laravel, testing, mockery

Currently I am trying to test a Facade call. I am sending slack notifications to notify me of something, however I don't want this to happen every time I run my test.

I am using the following: https://github.com/maknz/slack.
This enables me to do the following:

```
Slack::to('aChannel')->attach('someData')->send('moreData');
```

I'm trying to test this by doing the following:

```
Slack::shouldReceive('to')->once();
```

Now I think this is working, however the code is giving an error now since I can't do ->attach(.. *Error: Call to a member function attach() on null*

I think this is happening since I mock the object, it's null. I can't call the function.

Does anyone have experience with this situation and knows how I might be able to test this without breaking the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happened because you're using chained methods. You can update your test like so:

```
Slack::shouldReceive('to->attach->send')->once();
```

You may read more about this on [Mocking Demeter Chains And Fluent Interfaces here](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html).

Hope this solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, tried to pass the functions as an array. Didn't think of this. Thank you for the link also. Tests are now finished!